# Data Sharing between Sibling Functional Components - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have the main component as below.

```
const MainApp: React.FC = () => {

  return (
      <div>
        <DummyComp/>    
        <ComponentA />
        <ComponentB />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

"Component B" has some form elements and when it's value changes, I require all the form values to be passed to the "Component A".

All the examples that I found are not using Functional Components. So I am not sure how to create callback functions and use states in Functional Components.

Answer (score 1):

```
const MainApp: React.FC = () => {

 const [formData, setFormData ] = useState({});



  return (
      <div>
        <DummyComp/>    
        <ComponentA formData={formData} />
        <ComponentB onClick={setFormData} />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can edit formData object as you wish in ComponentB with setFormData method, and you can read the formData object in ComponentA.

Comment: Is it possible to update how to handle the  props in the component A and B.. thats the most confusing part.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Redux (Global State) to do this, OR use a state manage in the Main Component.

```
const MainApp: React.FC = () => {

 const [data, setData] = useState();

 useEffect(() => {
   setData() //anyhting initial
  },[formdata]);

    const handleData = (data) => {
     setData(data)
    }


  return (
      <div>
        <DummyComp/>    
        <ComponentA data={data}  />
        <ComponentB onformclick={handleData} />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Lets Suppose component A is like

```
const ComponentA: React.FC = ({props}) => {

const data = props.data; 

  return (
      <div>
        //any html here
        //example
        <div>
         {
          data ?
          data.property //any property existing on data
          :null
          }
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default ComponentB;
```

Lets Suppose component A is like

```
const ComponentA: React.FC = ({props}) => {

const [formdata, SetformData] = useState();

  return (
      <div>
        //form here 
        //any button or any element to submit form 
        <button onClick={()=>props.onformclick(formdata)}> submit </button>
      </div>
  );
}

export default ComponentB;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help by showing how to use the props in those 2 sibling components?